# How to display rich text in a gtk.MenuItem label?

Tags: python, string, pygtk, rtf, menuitem

I would like to display rich text in a `gtk.MenuItem()`, e.g. displaying **bold** text. So far I have only found that one could [pass in a string](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkmenuitem.html#method-gtkmenuitem--set-label).

Is it possible to display rich text in such a label? If so, how?
If not, how appalling that would be! :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set the menu bold, but you may set the label on it as bold by calling the child :

```
        label = menuItem.get_children()[0]
        label.set_markup("<b>Hi Pete!</b>")
```

Comment: Thanks ! I suppose one can immediately create the menuItem this way : gtk.MenuItem("<b>Hi Benjamin!</b>") but I did not try.

Comment: Well I didn't try either, but since there is a specific method for this, I doubt it is possible.