# How can I make the text of a GTK MenuItem bold using gtk-rs?

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk-rs

I use gtk-rs to implement a little of UI for an AppIndicator application. I would like to make certain menu items in my appindicator menu bold, but I can't figure out how to go about it.

The menu item is initialized like so:

```
let foobar = gtk::MenuItem::with_label("Foobar");
```

What is the magic incantation to make that label bold?

Comment: From a rendering perspective, bold or italic text might as well be a completely different font. You likely need to switch out the font being used with a separate bold version. For example when you download a font from https://fonts.google.com/, the zip folder will include a separate `.ttf` file for each style/weight of a given font.

Comment: Poking through the `gtk` docs, it sounds like `weight` might effect how strong/bold a font is. You may want to look for a `set_weight` function.

Comment: @Locke that's not how a GUI Toolkit should work. I don't want to use a different font than the system itself. The menu should integrate nicely with all the others on the system. I just noticed that nm-applet for example is an appindicator and has differently styled menu entries.

Comment: Have you tried the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189338/how-to-display-rich-text-in-a-gtk-menuitem-label, using HTML bold markers ?

Comment: @Magix I tried to but couldn't get it to work. Since this is Rust, it wasn't that obvious to me to get the child and set markup. I came up with this, it compiled, but didn't do anything:

`let mi = gtk::MenuItem::with_label("<b>Quit</b>");
    let label: Widget = mi.get_child().unwrap();
    label.downcast::<Label>().unwrap().set_markup("<b>Quit</b>");`